# conditional loop in mustache.js

Tags: jquery, mustache

How can I output `<hr>` after every iteration except last one with mustache.js. I tried javascript for loop but I couldn't get rid of last `<hr>`. (Some people suggest using handlebars.js but I would like stay with mustache.)

Here is my json (the list gets bigger as more employees get added)

```
    {
      employees: [
        {firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith"},
        {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"},
        {firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe"}    
       ]
    }
```

I want this html output:

```
John Smith
<hr>
John Doe
<hr>
Jane Doe
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looking at the [Mustache Manual](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html), you'll want to use what's referred to as "Inverted Sections". From the manual:

> An inverted section begins with a caret (hat) and ends with a slash.
>   That is {{^person}} begins a "person" inverted section while
>   {{/person}} ends it.
>
> While sections can be used to render text one or more times based on
>   the value of the key, inverted sections may render text once based on
>   the inverse value of the key. That is, they will be rendered if the
>   key doesn't exist, is false, or is an empty list.

To utilize this, you could add an extra attribute to the last employee to distinguish it.

JSON:

```
{
  "employees": [
    {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith"},
    {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"},
    {"firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Doe", "last": true}    
   ]
}
```

Mustache Template:

```
{{#employees}}
  {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
  {{^last}}
    <hr />
  {{/last}}
{{/employees}}
```

This is very similar to what the [Mustache Demo](http://mustache.github.com/#demo) showcases, using the "first" attribute on the first object in the array of colors.

Answer (score 10):

If the purpose of `<hr/>` is purely for style, why not use a CSS selector like `:not(:last-child)`?

JavaScript:

```
var tpl = "<ul>{{#employees}}<li>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</li>{{/employees}}</ul>",
        data = {
  "employees": [
    {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith"},
    {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"},
    {"firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Doe", "last": true}    
   ]
},
    html = Mustache.to_html(tpl, data);

document.write(html);
```

CSS:

```
li:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

[Here's a working jsFiddle to see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/maxbeatty/zPLJt/)